# How to fetch all objects in s3 buckets based on dates?

Tags: bash, shell, amazon-s3

Here is my usecase - objects in my buckets are suffixed with dates eg:
`file-2018-10-10` , `file-2018-10-15` etc.

If someone were to enter `2018-10-12`, then my tool should download the nearest file in future, which in this case would be `file-2018-10-15`.

For that I first plan to list the bucket and loop through all the S3-Keys.

1. Is it possible to list the keys 'reverse-sorted'
2. Is there any shell script example to list the 'reverse-sorted' list?

Comment: What are you using? Did you follow https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't list keys in reverse order, but you don't need to. You can specify the start key when you list a bucket's objects. In your case you would specify `file-2018-10-12` as `--start-after` parameter for the `list-object-v2` api.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-objects-v2.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is the answer to your first question.
You use the simple PHP reverse array function to reverse the array after fetching the result array.

```
  $files_name = $s3->listObjects(array('Bucket' => $bucketName, 'Prefix' => $prefix));
  $object2 = $files_name['Contents'];
  $object2 = array_reverse($object2);
```